# Getting Data Assigned to Individual Users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

I am building an application for the first time using ASP.NET MVC/Web API that has multiple user accounts with 'UserId', 'AccountId', 'ClientId' and 'EventId' as identifying fields. I am able to login the user, retrieve the UserId, but I cannot figure out how to get the AccountId, ClientId and EventId based on the logged in user.

```
object id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
ViewData["Id"] = id;
```

I have looked everywhere for help on this issue. I thought that it would be pretty straight forward but I have yet to find an answer. Thanks!

Comment: You can do that using `ApplicationUserManager` for finding users by their ids

Comment: Using `.FindById` method

Answer (score 2):

If you have derived the standard `IdentityUser` you can do it as follows:

```
// Create manager
 var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(
    new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(
        new ApplicationDbContext()))

// Find user
var user = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
var accountId = user.AccountId;
```

Here I am assuming you have used the name `ApplicationUser`;

So assuming your class is like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
      public int AccountId{ get; set; }
      public int ClientId{ get; set; }
      // etc
}
```